# Шаблон для сочинения ЕГЭ

Tags: общие-вопросы, егэ

У меня возникает проблема лишь при трактовке проблемы, учитель весь мозг проел что использовать старый шаблон (*В мире существует много проблем...*) нельзя. Так вот, как лучше начать вступление?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если вам нужен конструкция синонимичная "в мире много проблем", могу предложить следущий вариант:

*На современном этапе развития человечества, которое из-за расширившихся благодаря технологиям границ, стало менее однородным в своих цивилизационных и нравственных идеалах, все острее проявляются как старые "вечные" вопросы, так и новые, связанные с вызовами технократии и глобализации. Одну из проблем человеческого взаимодействия с (окружающим миром, обществом, самим собой, религией) и поднимает автор, данного текста*.

Comment: Прекрасное начало, а возможно ли добавить к нему риторические вопросы? К примеру: как телевидение влияет на человека? Опасно ли это влияние? Именно эти вопросы поднимает автор данного текста <Вставить ФИО >, только как дальше продолжить формулировку проблемы? Или этого достаточно?

Comment: @Seth, можно продолжать так как вашей душе угодно. Я лишь привёл один из вариантов конструкции синонимичной фразе "в мире много проблем".